# The exponential function intersects an $n$-th degree polynomial at no more than $n+1$ points.

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, exponential-function, analytic-geometry, roots

*How to show that:*

> The graph of the exponential function $f(x)=e^x$ intersects the graph of an $n$-degree polynomial $p(x)$ at no more than $n+1$ points.

I have in mind a proof using this observation that [A function with positive $n$-th derivative has at most $n$ roots – an inequality version of the Fundamental theorem of Algebra.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617106/a-function-with-positive-n-th-derivative-has-at-most-n-roots-an-inequality) However I'm wondering if there is a more direct proof, or if it is obvious from some well-known theorem.

---

**Motivation:**

I realized this should be true when thinking about "higher-order" of convexity properties of functions:

- [Geometric characterization of functions with positive third derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4617862/geometric-characterization-of-functions-with-positive-third-derivative)
- [Second-order star convex set: A set $S$ that any conics from $s_1\in S$ to $s_2\notin S$ does not reenter $S$ twice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618125/second-order-star-convex-set-a-set-s-that-any-conics-from-s-1-in-s-to-s-2)

Comment: Repeated application of Rolle's theorem (as in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4617112/42969 to your referenced question) is the most natural approach IMO. Whether you call it “repeated application” or “induction” does not make a difference.

Comment: Here is an example  that the bound is sharp, i.e. that $n+1$ intersection points can occur: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76427/42969

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to me: [Number of solutions of $P(x)=e^{ax}$ if $P$ is a polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/646092/42969)

Comment: @MartinR I missed that post. And indeed, all the proofs are essentially the same. Feel free to mark the question as a duplicate, I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideas:

1. Proof by induction.  When $f$ is degree $0$, it is a constant and $c=e^x$ has at most one solution.
2. Note that if $f(x)-e^x=0$ has $m$ solutions, then between each pair of consecutive solutions, there is a point where the derivative is $0$.  This means the derivative has at least $m-1$ zeros.
3. Apply the inductive hypothesis to the derivative $f'(x)-e^x$, since $f'(x)$ is of one lower degree.

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same argument as in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4617112/42969 to the referenced question?

Comment: Thank you for a simple and nice solution! (I changed the notation in your answer to make it consistent with the notation in the question, since I used $f$ for the exponential function.)

Comment: @MartinR I agree, essentially the proofs are the same. I hope yet to see some proof that will surprise me.